# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a webservice. I am getting 500 internal error.
webservice is running .I uses the following code

I am getting the error at this point:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Code:

```
    string requestxml = @"C\request.xml";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(requestxml);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    xmlDoc.WriteTo(tx);

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());



    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3993/test.asmx");

    request.Method = "POST";


    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());

     request.ContentType = "application/xml";


    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

stack trace

at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)\r\n   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)\r\n   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Powershell code

```
$TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost:3993/test.asmx");

$webRequest.Method = "POST";
$webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
$con = Get-Content .\Request.xml;
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($con);

$webRequest.ContentLength = $bytes.Length;
$ReqStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream();


$ReqStream.Write($bytes,0,$bytes.Length);
#$ReqStream.Flush();
$ReqStream.Close();
$response = $webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: We need to know the actual exception, and where it's actually happening within the code.

Comment: Enable debugging, and include the stack trace.

Comment: You should run the local iis for this , i suggest you to turn on two Visual Studio on project is the client the other one is server, after you turn the server [CTRL+F5] you take the address of the server url like you have done.<br/>
After that you go to the client and make the request, it should work.

Comment: @ Andrew when i call from powershell,the webservice is running perfectly responding.when i call from c#,it is showing this error

Comment: Show us the PowerShell code. It's doing something different.

Comment: If you're getting a 500, then IIS should be making an entry in the event log.  Check that and see what it says.  I'd hazard a guess it's a data format/conversion error, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Error 500 happens because there's something messed up in the output html page. To me, that means there's something wrong with the parameters you're passing to the web service and the WS is not smart enough to catch that problem. You might try it with a canned 'sw', one that you KNOW has worked before, and then look at YOUR 'sw' to find the problem.

Comment: @Pete Wilson, I am using the same request xml working in the powershell

Answer (score 2):

The 500 response indicates there is a problem in the webservice.  You need to debug the webservice, not the call to the service.  I would first verify that your method is being called, and then work on from there.

If your webservice is not being called, then you need to verify the XML that is being sent, and the URL for the webservice.

Comment: the webservice is running perfectly

Comment: Wrong! the webservice is NOT running perfectly if you get 500. That is, 500 is showing up because the WS is doing something wrong. The only question is, why and what is it doing wrong. The most likely "why" is that 'sw' is messed up and the WS is not smart enough to handle it.

Comment: @ i can call the webservice from powershell,i am getting the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was not problem the WebService. The problem was in the XML request that i was sending to the server.